# windows security alert windows firewall has blocked some features of this program message coming for every new build of my application

Tags: windows, firewalls, .net, ftp

I made an application which uses ftp so windows shows  `windows security alert windows firewall has blocked some features of this program` message for every new version of my application any idea how to fix this so user does not have to press unblock for every new build of my application?

I publish my application using visual studio publish option & new version get pushed to client machines automatically. details for this deployment are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

e.g.
For 1.2 version it will only ask for windows firewall permissions only once but for 1.3 it will ask again.

Comment: Are you changing the image path and name with each build? i.e is it c:\progra~1\jaminator_1.2\jm12.exe before upgrade and c:\progra~1\jaminator_1.3\jm13.exe after?

Comment: @GrahamHill yes for some reason its changing the path details http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d3df36dc-9f37-4bff-9c18-a9d2255d5bb1

Answer (score 1):

This is by design in the windows firewall security model - if it thinks the application has changed it doesn't know whether that is a malicious change so reverts to the default 'block' until a connection is approved by the user.